# Complex Plane ( $\arg(z)$)

Tags: complex-numbers

Sketch the following regions of the complex plane. For each, say whether it is open, closed, or neither, and whether it is connected. No proofs necessary.
$$\left\{z \in \mathbb{C}\mid -\dfrac{\pi}{2} < \arg(z) < \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right\}$$

So, for this problem I am not sure what $\arg(z)$ means because our teacher never went over it. So I have no idea how to attack this problem. Could someone help explain to me what $\arg(z)$ means and how I would go about drawing this in the complex plane please?

Thank You

Comment: this the argument. When you draw the point (a,b) which we can identify with $a+bi$ then the angle from $X$-axis and the line joining $(a,b)$ with $(0,0)$ here you have details

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29

Answer (score 0):

$\arg(z)$ is the angle between the line joining your point $z=a+ib$ and the origin, in the complex plane. It becomes visually striking when you are introduced to the polar form of complex numbers, but from the situation you describe, you have just started working on complex numbers.

So, you're looking at the region of all the points in the complex plane that are form an angle between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$ with the origin. Basically, you're going counter-clockwise from the negative imaginary axis (the vertical axis), to the line making a 45° ($\frac{\pi}{4}$) angle with respect to the origin.

This region is (simply) connected, as you can partition it in as many subsets as you want, and it is open, as it extends to infinity (i.e. it is not completely bounded).

Comment: Maybe I don't have the same definition, but how does partitioning into as many sets as we want tie in with simple connection?

Comment: @GPerez In the sense that you can't represent this region as the union of two disjoint subregions, i.e. there are no "holes".

Comment: Right, but isn't that just plain Conectedness? There are non simply connected sets that are connected, or even path-connected.

Comment: @GPerez But isn't every simply connected space path-connected?

Comment: Exactly, but what I mean is that the converse is false.

Comment: That not all path-connected spaces are simply connected?

Comment: Indeed, that's what I mean.

Comment: @GPerez Sure, I agree. Now, coming from a Physics background, I know next to nothing in topology. So, is the region described in my answer simply connected or not?

Comment: Yes it is! Although not for the reason you state. It is simply commected because its fundamental group is trivial (and neither am I an algebraic topology expert so I don't know how to justify this, athough when I was studying the topic I would have known, and now I can just "tell" that it is).

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated to explain without drawing; the best, it seems to me, is to draw a picture and then invite people to invent their own examples.
There are many notions required in the exercise but they are all very intuitive and easy to understand intuitively with the support of drawing.

- An argument of $Z'$ is $\color{red}\alpha$ expressed in radians; An argument of $Z''$ is $\color{green}{-\beta}$ expressed in radians;
- $S:=\left\{z \in \mathbb{C}\mid -\dfrac{\pi}{2} < \arg(z) < \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right\}$ is all in one piece: it is said to be "connected" in mathematics.
- Since the inequalities are strict and we cannot speak of the argument of $0$, for each point $Z$ of $S$, we have a disk with center $Z$, which is completely contained in $S$: we says $S$ is "open" in mathematics.

These notions (connected, open, closed, ...) are basic notions of the part of mathematics called "general topology" and the complex plane is the ideal place to become familiar with.
[image]